# integrate this double integral by any method you can.

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, definite-integrals

I'm having trouble with this double integral:

$$\int_0^2\int_0^{2-x} \exp\left(\frac{x−y}{x+y}\right)\text dy\,\text dx$$

Comment: this is first one.

Comment: $dxdy$? or $dydx$?

Comment: y varies between 0 and 2-x

Comment: first of all i would recommend a change of variables $x-y=v, \quad  x+y=u$ with jacobian $1/2$

Comment: It is not appropriate to phrase questions posted here in a way suitable for assigning homework.  That is probably the reason why some people are voting to close the question.  They ought to have told you that, but around here that usually doesn't happen.

Comment: I suspect pursuing the substitution proposed above by "tired" will do the job.

Comment: homework? i am graduated in computer software engineering  :D just remembering these stuff for fun.

Comment: >by any method |||  

Alright, I did it numerically, the answer came out to be 2.350402412875456

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1019234/double-integral-change-of-variables?rq=1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The integral is one over the $2$-simplex $\Delta_2(2) = \{ (x,y ) : x, y \ge 0, x+ y \le 2 \}$.

One standard trick to deal with integral over $d$-simplex of the form
$$\Delta_d(L) = \{ (x_1, x_2, \ldots, x_d ) : x_i \ge 0, \sum_{i=1}^d x_i  \le L \}$$
is convert it to one over the $d$-cuboid $[0,L] \times [0,1]^{d-1}$ through following change of variables

$$\begin{align}
\lambda &= x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_d\\
\lambda\mu_1 &= x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{d-1}\\
\lambda\mu_1\mu_2 &= x_1 + x_2 + \cdots + x_{d-2}\\
&\;\;\vdots\\
\lambda\mu_1\mu_2\cdots\mu_{d-1} &= x_1
\end{align}
$$
Under such change of variables, an integral of $(x_1,\ldots,x_d)$ over $\Delta_d(L)$ becomes an integral of $(\lambda,\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_{d-1})$ over 
$[0,L] \times [0,1]^{d-1}$.

For the integral at hand, let $\lambda = x + y$ and $x = \mu\lambda$.
The area element can be rewritten as

$$dx \wedge dy = dx \wedge d(x+y) = d(\mu \lambda) \wedge d\lambda = \lambda d\mu \wedge d\lambda$$

So the integral becomes

$$\int_{\Delta_2(2)} \exp\left(\frac{x-y}{x+y}\right)dxdy
= \int_0^2 \int_0^1 e^{2\mu - 1} \lambda d\mu d\lambda
= \left(\int_0^2 \lambda d\lambda \right)\left(\int_0^1 e^{2\mu-1} d\mu\right)\\
= 2 \times \frac{1}{2e}(e^2 - 1)
= 2\sinh(1)
\approx 2.35040238728760291376476370119120163
$$

Comment: thanks for the clear answer.

Comment: Did I understand this correctly: For $\lambda$ alone, we treat it as a variable but for $\mu_1 \lambda$ we treat $\lambda$ as a constant. And if we had $\mu_2 \mu_1 \lambda$ then $\mu_1 \lambda$ would be treated as constants?

Comment: @grdgfgr Are you referring to the $d(\mu\lambda)\wedge d\lambda = \lambda d\mu\wedge d\lambda$ part? In that case, the answer is no, both $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are variables all the time. The full derivation of above should be
$$d(\mu\lambda)\wedge d\lambda = 
(\lambda d\mu + \mu d\lambda) \wedge d\lambda = 
\lambda d\mu\wedge d\lambda + \mu d\lambda \wedge d\lambda = 
\lambda d\mu\wedge d\lambda
$$
The last equality is true because wedge product between 1-forms are anti-commutative. i.e for any function $f, g$, $df \wedge dg = - dg \wedge df$.
In particular $d\lambda \wedge d\lambda = 0$.

Comment: Remember, if you exchange two rows (or columns) of a matrix, the determinant get an extra minus sign. Just think of above manipulation of differential forms as a efficient ways for computing the Jacobian.